# Get the index path of last row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 1 section and `numberOfRows:` from `NSMutableArray`.

What I want here is that whenever `UITableView` appears the scroll view must scroll to last row.

For this I want `indexPath` of last row. How to get it?

I know this question is answered many times. But none of those approaches worked for me.

Here is the code I tried

```
-(NSIndexPath*)lastIndexPath{
     NSInteger sectionsAmount = [myTableView numberOfSections];
     NSInteger rowsAmount = [myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:sectionsAmount-1];
     NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(rowsAmount - 1) inSection:(sectionsAmount - 1)];
     return lastIndexPath;
 }
```

Comment: You can use array last index.

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain what isn't working.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: @Hemant can you please explain how can i do it with array last index.

Comment: @rmaddy Log shows no error.App just crashes.

Comment: Use the debugger and figure out where any why it crashes. No one can help if you don't provide any useful details.

Comment: @SushilSharma from where are you calling your method lastIndexPath?

Comment: `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[arrayObject count] inSection:0];`
  You don't need to use -1 because array and tableview count both start from 0.

Comment: @devgr I am calling this method in viewWillAppear. and when app crashes,the breakpoint is in AppDelegate' makeKeyAndVisible..... Totally disappointed,.

Comment: @SushilSharma try calling in viewDidAppear and see what happens. If it crashes please post the crash log.

Comment: @devgr yupp .... its working now.Thanks a lot dear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have only one section yu can find the indexpath with

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[yourArray count]-1 inSection:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`scrollToRowAtIndexPath` should work.

In `viewWillAppear`, try this:

```
[theTableView reloadData];    
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumberHere inSection:sectionNumberHere];
[theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Comment: No, I want to detect the index path of last row.